# Having problem to set the color of the two histograms separately

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I'm trying to analyze the `wine-quality` dataset. There are two datasets: the `red wine` dataset and the `white wine`. I combine them together to form the `wine_df`. And I want to see the average quality of the wine group by color, I try to plot them. And I want to give the red histogram red color, the white histogram  white color. But these two histograms are always the same color. It seems that the **'color'** parameter in the `plot()` doesn't work. And the result of the color is always the first one I set in the list `colors`. What should I do? Thanks for your answer!

```
python
colors = ['white','red']
plt.style.use('ggplot')
color_means = wine_df.groupby('color')['quality'].mean()
color_means.plot(kind='bar', title='Average Wine Quality by Color', color=colors, alpha=.7)
plt.xlabel('colors', fontsize=18)
plt.ylabel('Quality', fontsize=18)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure how your data looks like. However, I used the data from the github and added a new column to each dataframe with the value associated with its color. That is, `red` value for `red_wine` and `white` value for `white_wine`.

**Code:**

```
## Data read
red_wine = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nishanthgandhidoss/Wine-Quality/master/data/winequality-red.csv',
                      sep = ';')
white_wine = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nishanthgandhidoss/Wine-Quality/master/data/winequality-white.csv', 
                        sep = ';')

## Add a column to each data to identify the wine color 
red_wine['color'] = 'red'
white_wine['color'] = 'white'

## Combine the two dataframes    
wine_df = pd.concat([red_wine, white_wine])

## Histogram with different colors
colors = ['red','white']
plt.style.use('ggplot')
color_means = wine_df.groupby('color')['quality'].mean()
color_means.plot(kind='bar', title='Average Wine Quality by Color', color=colors, alpha=.7)
plt.xlabel('colors', fontsize=18)
plt.ylabel('Quality', fontsize=18)
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Firstly, thank you for your advice. While I paste your code to my own jupyter notebook environment, the result is still two red histograms...... I guess there maybe some problems with my environment. So I reinstall the `matplotlib` and `pandas` packages, and it doesn't work.... still two red histograms. 
And I check the `pandas plot()` documentation, there is no `'color'` parameter, I really don't no what to do next.

Comment: Do you mind sharing the version of `pandas` and 'matplotlib'. This can be checked using `pd.__version__` and `import matplotlib as m` 
`m.__version__`

Comment: It works! Thank you for your patience! When there is two histograms, there colors are right: one is red and one is white.

Comment: But I still have another problem…… Could you please answer it, thanks a lot orz!
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54246799/the-histograms-color-and-its-labels-are-inconsistent

Comment: It was answered before i could type my answer. :)